# ITelemetryInitializer.Initialize never being called when using Serilog with ApplicationInsights in Console application

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-application-insights, serilog

I am configuring DI as follows in my .NET Core 3.1 Console application:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, TelemetryInitializer>();
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService(instrumentationKey);
```

In `appSettings.json` I have:

```json
"Serilog": {
  "Using": [
    "Serilog.Sinks.Console",
    "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
  ],
  "MinimumLevel": "Information",
  "WriteTo": [
    {
      "Name": "Console",
      "Args": {
        "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj} {Properties:j}{NewLine}{Exception}",
        "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Compact.CompactJsonFormatter, Serilog.Formatting.Compact"
      }
    },
    {
      "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
      "Args": {
        "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information",
        "InstrumentationKey": "...",
        "telemetryConverter": "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter, Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights",
        "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj} {Properties:j}{NewLine}{Exception}",
        "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Compact.CompactJsonFormatter, Serilog.Formatting.Compact"
      }
    }
  ],
  "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ]
}
```

Serilog is configured as follows:

```cs
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
        loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)
    )
    .UseConsoleLifetime()
    .Build()
    .Run()
```

My initializer class:

```cs
public class TelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        telemetry.Context.Cloud.RoleName = "something-something";
    }
}
```

The `Initialize` method however is *not* being called when I log using `ILogger`. If I resolve `TelemetryClient` directly and log using that, `Initialize` *is* called.

Am I missing some configuration for Serilog?

Comment: To better repro/debug the issue, please provide a working sample and the packages you're using:).

Comment: Given that @krishg has already supplied the answer, I might save myself the trouble, unless someone else would find that helpful!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to be a glitch of `Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights`. When initializing sink from config ([code reference](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-applicationinsights/blob/master/src/Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights/LoggerConfigurationApplicationInsightsExtensions.cs#L99)), it creates a new `TelemetryClient` which results in an active `TelemetryConfiguration` before the registered `TelemetryInitializer` could be associate with it.

To get the `TelemetryInitilizer` injected with Active configuration, it needs to have the `TelemetryClient` instance created once before the Serilog initializes the App Insights sink. Otherwise it would be too late to respect it since internally `AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService` registers `TelemetryClient` as Singleton. So below is my working code which just makes a dummy resolve of `TelemetryClient` before initializing loggerConfiguration of Serilog.

```cs
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService(instrumentationKey);
                    services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, TelemetryInitializer>();
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                })
                .UseSerilog((hostingContext, serviceProvider, loggerConfiguration) => {
                    serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<TelemetryClient>(); // just a dummy resolve
                    loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration);
                })
                .UseConsoleLifetime();
    }
```

Option 2 is to create a custom TelemetryConverter which can update required context instead of using the `Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter`. That would remove the reliance on initializer.

Option 3 is to switch to code based setup instead of configuration which would allow you to pass `TelemetryClient` or `TelemetryConfiguration` instance like https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-applicationinsights#configuring. But that may not  be as declarative as configuration based approach.

Comment: `dummy resolve` worked great for me as well!!